# twoSum function behaves differently with different array inputs

Tags: go

When I run the following code, I get the expected answer `[3, 4]`, which is the index of the 2 numbers that add up to my target variable. However, when I change the myArray input to `[]int{1,2,3,4,6,11,4,12}` (I deleted the last 6), I get a panic. Please help me understand why this is happening.

```
func twoSum (nums []int, target int) []int {
    length := len(nums) - 1
    for i := range nums[:length] {
        for j := range nums[i + 1:] {
            if nums[i] + nums[j] == target {
                return []int{i, j}
                break
            }
        }
    }
    panic("should never happen")
}

func main() {
    myArray := []int{1,2,3,4,6,11,4,12}
    myTarget := 10
    fmt.Println(twoSum(myArray, myTarget))
}
```

Comment: You get a panic because you're calling it in the last line of the `twoSum` function definition.

Comment: What panic? A complete question will include all relevant error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for j := range nums[i + 1:] {`

This does not work like you expect: `j` here is a 0-based index of a new slice, that you obtained after you resliced the `nums` with `nums[i+1:]`.

If you still want to have the absolute index in the `nums` slice you need to offset it manually, eg:

```
jx := j + i + 1
```

and then use `jx` instead of `j`

Demo: https://play.golang.org/p/s7_tcHvu6fB

Alternatively you may have used a good old indexed `for` instead of `for-range` as a nested loop:

```
for j := i + 1; j < length; j++ {
```

Demo: https://play.golang.org/p/-yF7cWYgYri

Comment: Or use `for i, ni := range ...` and `for _, nj := range ...` and skip most of the indexing altogether.

Comment: @muistooshort my first thought as well, but they need to return indexes of the found items.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's sort of important :)

Comment: Zerkms, thank you for the explanation regarding j being a 0-based index of a new slice. I am used to Python. There is definitely value in using an indexed for loop, it seems more clear what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

`for i := range nums[:length]`, you will get i's values as `0,1,2,3...`

`for j := range nums[i+1:]`, you will get j's values as `0,1,2,3...`

Then, when you calculate the sum of `nums[i]+nums[j]`, you actually calculate `nums[0]+nums[0]`, which is `1+1=2` instead of `1+2=3`.